# Creating multiple controllable timers

Tags: javascript, function, object

How would I go about making this whole thing into a function that creates new controllable timers?

```
var seconds = 0;
var interval;
//when you want the timer to stop
var endTime = 55;

function checkTimer() {
if (seconds == endTime) {
    restartPause();

}};

//reset timer
function restart() {
pause();
seconds = 0; interval = setInterval(function() {console.log(seconds); seconds++; checkTimer()}, 1000);
};

//pause timer
function pause() {
  clearInterval(interval);
};

//play timer
function start() {
  pause();
  interval = setInterval(function() {console.log(seconds); seconds++; checkTimer()}, 1000);
};

//Restart and Pause, for when the video ends
function restartPause() {
restart();
pause();
};

function timeChange(n) {
seconds = n;
}
```

Say I want to have the ability to create multiple timers like so

```
var myTimer = new timer();
var anotherTimer = new timer();
var thirdTimer = new timer();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways to do this. If you are using a browser that can handle ES6 classes, you can make a class that defines all these functions as methods. The traditional way to do this in Javascript is to define a function and then add the other functions to the `prototype`. You'll need to access the variables and functions with `this` from the instances. Here's an example that uses a few of your functions that should show how it works:

```js
function Timer(endTime){
    // define instance properties
    this.endTime = endTime;
    this.interval = undefined
    this.seconds = 0
}

// Define methods
Timer.prototype.pause = function() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
}
Timer.prototype.start = function(){
    this.pause()
    // you should use arrow => functions when passing methods to event handler
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {console.log(this.seconds); this.seconds++; this.checkTimer()}, 1000)
}
Timer.prototype.checkTimer = function() {
    if (this.seconds >= this.endTime) {
        this.pause();
    }
};
Timer.prototype.restart = function() {
    this.seconds = 0; 
    this.start()
};

// create a timer that will stop in 10 and start it
let t = new Timer(10)
t.start()

// create another
let t2 = new Timer(10)
t2.start()

// stop the second one in a few seconds
setTimeout(() => t2.pause(), 3100)
```

Note that timers are not very accurate, so if you need something with accurate time you might need to look for a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should create "class" (not really class, there aren't classes in ES5, but function that can be used with `new`. For morer information, see [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)). Then, for any "class" there are member variables that they only of the currenct instnce of that class. For example, for creating class `Timer`, use the following code:

```
function Timer() {
  // Private memebers, accessed only inside the class

  var seconds = 0;
  var interval;
  // When you want the timer to stop
  var endTime = 55;

  // Private functions

  var that = this; // For the intervalFunc function, I explained in my comment below
  var intervalFunc = function() {
    console.log(seconds);
    seconds++;
    that.checkTimer();
  };

  // Public functions, acessed to anyone have an instance of the class

  this.checkTimer = function() {
    if (seconds == endTime) {
      this.restartPause();
    }
  };

  // Reset timer
  this.restart = function() {
    this.pause();
    seconds = 0;
    interval = setInterval(intervalFunc, 1000);
  };

  // Pause timer
  this.pause = function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
  };

  // Play timer
  this.start = function() {
    this.pause();
    interval = setInterval(intervalFunc, 1000);
  };

  // Restart and Pause, for when the video ends
  this.restartPause = function() {
    this.restart();
    this.pause();
  };

  this.timeChange = function(n) {
    seconds = n;
  };
}



// Create instances of the class
var t1 = new Timer(), t2 = new Timer();
t1.start(); // t2 doesn't start!
t2.start();
t2.pause(); // t1 doesn't pause!
```

#### Edit:

when you're accessing from the class to public member, the `this` keyword is required! (But no when you're accessing to private members).

Comment: Thanks @Chayim Friedman! It's giving me an error on line 14 saying this.checkTimer() is not a function, yet it's still working. I'm new to javascript so I didn't know how to use new exactly.

Comment: `new` creates an instance of object, see the link I gave. And the error is because `this` is changed in JS, see [this article](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/). I updated my answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
 class Timer {
   constructor() {
     this.seconds = 0;
     this.endTime = 55;
     this.interval = null;
   }

   checkTimer() {
     if (this.seconds === this.endTime) {
       this.restartPause();
     }
   }

   restart() {
     this.pause();
     this.seconds = 0;
     this.interval = setInterval(() => {
       console.log(this.seconds);
       this.seconds++;
       this.checkTimer();
     }, 1000);
   }

   pause() {
     clearInterval(this.interval);
   }

   start() {
     this.pause();
     this.interval = setInterval(() => {
       console.log(this.seconds);
       this.seconds++;
       this.checkTimer();
     }, 1000);
   }

   restartPause() {
     this.restart();
     this.pause();
   }

   timeChange(n) {
     this.seconds = n;
   }
 }
```

---

```
 const timer1 = new Timer();
 timer1.start();

 const timer2 = new Timer();
 timer2.start();
```